# Shopify CLI - Ngrok error when serving app

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopify-app, ngrok

I am on a windows 10 machine and trying to use the Shopify App CLI to create apps, but I am running into some errors.

First I installed ruby so I could use the gem command to install the Shopify App CLI, as explained [here](https://shopify.github.io/shopify-app-cli/getting-started/install/).

When running `shopify version` as explained in the above documentation, I get the following output:
`bash: shopify: command not found`

After googling for a bit I found a solution to this problem, by running `shopify.bat version`. With this command I can use the CLI.

Moving on, I tried following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIXN032XJJ8) tutorial to create my first Shopify App. I used `shopify.bat create node` to create my app, moved into the folder and ran `shopify.bat serve` to serve my app locally.

**Now the following problem arises:**

It starts promising by installing ngrok:

[image]

But after waiting for a bit, I get the following output (Sorry for the screenshot, I could not get it to look normal with inline code):

[image]

What I also notice is that it uses `C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.4.0/` as the path to the CLI, but when looking on Google, most people have `/home/[USER]/.shopify-app-cli/` as the path to the CLI. This path does not exist on my machine.

So I would like to know why first of all the serving of the app won't work, because ngrok can't be found, and second why `~/home/user/.shopify-app-cli` does not exist.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: You can format copy-pasted code by highlighting it and pressing control/command + K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think modern Windows come with Linux now. Since the Internet runs on Linux, you might find development and following tutorials much easier if you use Linux, since all these inconveniences of Windows disappear. Unless you are already super handy with all the quirks of Windows to work around their results, it could be your ticket!

That being said, I mastered this development pattern using *nix and it remains pretty advanced to actually have a smooth workflow for both localhost and production development. Ngrok itself is painful without paying for the service and using puma-dev and puma-ngrok... I laugh when I think about how those essentials running under Windows will be for you.

Comment: Thank you David. After reading your comment I started looking into WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which I have been procrastinating on looking into for months. It was easy to get started and resolved all my issues! 

Regarding ngrok, I read a lot of comments about it being painful to use, also regarding amount of request per minute etc. I have no idea if I can use something else, because the Shopify CLI automatically uses the ngrok service. Will look more into that later.

Thanks again.